# Azure function v3 not building in VS studio 2019

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Having troubling with setting up Azure Function project. When i create new project with Azure function v3, i am unable to build due to receiving the following error message.

> Metadata generation failed. Exit code: '-2146232797' Error: 'Assert FailureExpression: [Recursive resource lookup bug]Description: Infinite recursion during resource lookup within System.Private.CoreLib.  This may be a bug in System.Private.CoreLib, or potentially in certain extensibility points such as assembly resolve events or CultureInfo names.

Even if i try creating an empty solution of Azure function it still fails to build.

I have the following setup:

- .Net Core 3.1 installed
- Downloaded Azure Functions Core Tools v3 (Version 3.0.2245 Latest)
- Running on the latest VS Studio 2019 (Version 16.5.3)

I have tried working through VS code and run into same problem :|

Comment: What the version of azure function core tools you are using? Have you update to the latest version?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu I am running on the latest version of azure function core tools (3.0.2245)

Comment: Try to update the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to the latest version.

Comment: Hi @JoeyCai it is on the latest version of 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate the issue but I see a successful build. I have the following set up :

- Net Core 3.1
- Azure Functions Core Tools v3
- VS Studio 2019 (Version 16.7.0)

I have created a Http trigger function
[image]

However, I have also followed https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4649#issuecomment-511587424
and made sure I am using the latest version of the package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

[image]

Is it any different from what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.9 is working fine.